# Login php code keeps refreshing?

Tags: php, html

I'm having an issue with my login.php page not logging in, I can't work out why it keeps refreshing the page whenever I attempt to login. I'm using my index.php to redirect straight to my login.php not sure if this is the issue as before I change this it was working. Any ideas?

**Index.php**

```
<?php
    header("Location: Login.php");
?>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php
ob_clean();session_start(); 

if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
}

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$Username = $_POST['username'];
$EnteredPassword = $_POST['password'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (is_dir("USERS/".$Username) === true){
        $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$Username."/Password.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
        $CorrectPassword = fgets($myFile);
        fclose($myFile);

        if ($CorrectPassword == $EnteredPassword){
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            header("Location: Home.php");       
        }

        else {
            echo '<font color="#FF0000"><p align="center">Username or Password incorrect please try again</p></font>';
        }
    }

    else {
        echo '<font color="#FF0000"><p align="center">Username or Password incorrect please try again</p></font>';
    }
}   
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Project Archive - Login</title>

        <link href="CSS/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="CSS/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
        <script src="JAVASCRIPT/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body link="black">
        <div class="gridContainer clearfix"> 
            <div id="headerLoginDiv">
                <div id="titleLoginDiv">
                    <p>Project Archive</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h1 align="center">Login</h1>
            <h3 align="center">Welcome. Please login to continune.</h3>
            <form method="post" action="index.php">
            <div id="userNameLoginDiv">
                <p align="center">Username:</p>
                <input type="text" name="username" size="12">
            </div>  

            <div id="userPasswordLoginDiv">
                <p align="center">Password:</p>
                <input type="password" name="password" size="12">
            </div>

            <div id="loginBtnDiv">
                <input id="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
            </div> 
        </form>            
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, if you go to `index.php`, you are asking the browser to go to `login`, irrespective of whether the user is logged in or not:

```
<?php
    header("Location: Login.php"); // This blindly redirects the user to the login page.
?>
```

Instead of the above code, check and send the user:

```
<?php
    // Start the session.
    session_start();
    // Instead check if the user is logged in and then redirect.
    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
      header("Location: Login.php");
?>
```

Also, don't forget to start your session with `session_start()` at the beginning.

Comment: Does it not need `session_start()` at start of script ??

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks for suggestion `#same_name`... :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Right. We are mentioning us, which involves `#Mentionception`